# C Program will not calculate min and max (large and small)

Tags: c, range

I cannot seem to figure out why I am not getting the correct values for large and small. 
I am supposed to find the range of the n numbers given, do I have to set large and small to something before the loop?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //Declaring Variables
    int i, number, sum = 0, value, large, small;
    double avg;

            //User Input
            printf("Enter the number of elements you want to compute.\n");
            scanf("%d", &number);
            printf("Enter %d values.\n", number);

            //Loop to grab values
            for(i=0;i<number;i++)
            {
                    scanf("%d", &value);
                    large = value;
                    small = value;
                    if(value > large)
                            large = value;
                    if(value < small)
                            small = value;
                    //Sum Calculation
                    sum = sum + value;
                    //Average Calculation
                    avg = (((double)sum)/number);
            }

            printf("The sum of the %d numbers is: %d\n", number,sum);
            printf("The avg of the %d numbers is: %.2f\n", number, avg);
            printf("The largest number is: %d\n", large);
            printf("The smallest number is: %d\n", small);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to initiate small and large to appropriate values first, for example, set large to -10000 (smaller than smallest possible input value) and small to 10000 (larger than largest possible input value). and you only need to compute avg once after the for loop.

Comment: Or, set max and min from the first value read. Thereafter, you compare new values with the prevailing max and min.

Answer (score 1):

```
                large = value;
                small = value;
                // point A
                if(value > large)
                        large = value;
                if(value < small)
                        small = value;
```

At point A above, `large`, `small`, and `value` now contain the same value. The subsequent `if` statements won't ever take effect. You probably only wanted to those first two lines when `i == 0`.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand how to fix it. I see now that the if statement isn't being read.

Comment: it has later been suggested in another answer that you can use an `if` statement to execute those two lines only under a given condition

Answer (score 0):

Let me provide you with 2 possible approaches to fix your code:

Option 1.Initialize large and small outside the loop:
Since large and small are integers you can initialize them "outside" the for loop as follows:

```
int large = INT_MIN;
int small = INT_MAX;
```

And remove the statements:

```
large = value;
small = value;
```

from your for loop.

Since your aim is to calculate max and min respectively, you can initialize large to the smallest possible integer and also initialize small to largest possible integer.

The constants INT_MIN and INT_MAX are defined in "limits.h" header file.

Option 2.Change the code in your loop:

We need to understand that the variables large and small need to be initialized only "once" when the loop begins (i.e. when i == 0).
If you keep setting them every time you run through the loop, then they will keep getting overwritten and your min/max values will be inconsistent.

So change your code to the following:

```
if (i == 0) {
    large = value;
    small = value;
}
```

Side note: Calculate your average outside the loop "after" computing the entire sum.